# Access violation writing location 0x0120FA68

Tags: c++

So i'm trying to make a program for c++ that will split up text by spaces and I keep getting the error Access violation writing location 0x0120FA68. Here's the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::vector<char*> testVector;

    char* string1 = "test f";

    char seperators[] = " ";
    char* token1;
    char *next_token1;

    int counter = 0;
    token1 = strtok_s(string1, seperators, &next_token1);

    while (token1 != NULL)
    {
        if (token1 != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "\n" << token1 << std::endl;
            testVector.push_back(token1);
            token1 = strtok_s(NULL, seperators, &next_token1);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << testVector.at(0);
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is anything in the vector before trying to output the first element?

Comment: Why you are not using C++'s containers for strings and C++ algorithms for manipulating containers?

Comment: what do you mean? I'm new to this kind of stuff. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The `strtok()` family of functions modify their input strings.  You are calling it on a string literal, which some compilers store in memory that is not user writeable.  You can fix this by using `strcpy()` to copy the string literal into a buffer that you are then free to modify.

Comment: sorry but how do i do that because in what im using it gives me an error that says Error 1 error C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead.

Comment: You can safely ignore that warning -- Microsoft has a habit of "deprecating" standard C library functions that they have deemed dangerous, and recommending their own nonstandard replacements.   But go ahead and use strcpy_s() if the warning bothers you...just be aware that if you ever have to port your code to another system, you'll have to remove or reimplement the MS version of those routines.

Comment: i'd rather use the strcpy() but it prevents the program from even starting

Comment: is there a way to fix it because im using visual studio